# Return values from json data in SQL Server 2016

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016, how do I return "PageSize", "Total", and "NumberOfPages" values with my sample code? I'm pulling column headings with no data.

I want to see:

[SQL query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Nx2.jpg)

Code:

```
DECLARE @jsonData NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @jsonData = N'{
  "PageSize": 500,
  "PageNumber": 2,
  "Total": 994,
    "Items": [
    {
      "Id": 23004801096147,
      "StatusName": "Open",
      "CompanyName": "Microsoft",
      "JobTitle": "Project Manager"
    },
    {
      "Id": 23004801096147,
      "StatusName": "Closed",
      "CompanyName": "Salesforce",
      "JobTitle": "Marketing Manager"
    }
 ],
      "NumberOfPages": 1024
}'
```

--Try 1

```
SELECT
JSON_VALUE(fh.value, '$.PageSize') AS [PageSize],
JSON_VALUE(fh.value, '$.Total') AS [Total],
JSON_VALUE(fh.value, '$.NumberOfPages') AS [NumberOfPages]
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonData, '$.FileHeader') as fh
```

--Try 2

```
SELECT 'PageSize' as 'PageSize', 'Total' as 'Total', 'NumberOfPages' as 
'NumberOfPages'
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonData, '$.FileHeader') as fh
```

--Try 3

```
SELECT 'PageSize' as 'PageSize', 'Total' as 'Total', 'NumberOfPages' as 
'NumberOfPages'
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonData) as fh
```

--Try 4

```
SELECT 'PageSize' as 'PageSize', 'Total' as 'Total', 'NumberOfPages' as 
'NumberOfPages'
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonData)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL server 2016+ JSON:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Here's an example using your data:

```
   DECLARE @jsonData NVARCHAR(MAX)

   SET @jsonData = N'{
     "PageSize": 500,
     "PageNumber": 2,
     "Total": 994,
       "Items": [
       {
         "Id": 23004801096147,
         "StatusName": "Open",
         "CompanyName": "Microsoft",
         "JobTitle": "Project Manager"
       },
       {
         "Id": 23004801096147,
         "StatusName": "Closed",
         "CompanyName": "Salesforce",
         "JobTitle": "Marketing Manager"
       }
    ],
         "NumberOfPages": 1024
   }'

   --Using OPENJSON and "WITH"
   SELECT
   [PageSize]
   , [PageNumber]
   , [Total]
   , [NumberOfPages]
   FROM OPENJSON(@jsonData)
   WITH(
   [PageSize] BIGINT '$.PageSize'
   ,[PageNumber] BIGINT '$.PageNumber'
   ,[Total] BIGINT '$.Total'
   ,[NumberOfPages] BIGINT '$.NumberOfPages'
   )

   --This is how you could accomplish the same with JSON_VALUE
   SELECT
   JSON_VALUE(@jsonData, '$.PageSize') AS [PageSize],
   JSON_VALUE(@jsonData, '$.PageNumber') AS [PageNumber],
   JSON_VALUE(@jsonData, '$.Total') AS [Total],
   JSON_VALUE(@jsonData, '$.NumberOfPages') AS [NumberOfPages]
```

Comment: Thank you Tim.  That works!  I also came across another way that worked:

Comment: SELECT top 1
    JSON_VALUE(@jsonData, '$.PageSize') AS [PageSize],
    JSON_VALUE(@jsonData, '$.Total') AS [Total],
    JSON_VALUE(@jsonData, '$.NumberOfPages') AS [NumberOfPages]
    FROM OPENJSON(@jsonData)